# WinAPI createFile function 2

Tags: c++, winapi, createfile

i wrote some code to createfile in c++
it compiles without errors, but it doesn't create any file.. 
Can anyone tell me what is wrong ?
thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        HANDLE hfile;
        char data[] = "some text to write into file";       

        hfile = CreateFile(
               L"c:\name.txt",              
               GENERIC_WRITE, 
               0,
               NULL,
               CREATE_NEW,
               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
               NULL);

        /*
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        { 
            cout << "Unable to create file \n";

        }
        */
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Comment: Please tell me you're not going to post a question on SO for every error you encounter in your app.

Answer (score 4):

Also in C++ you need to escape the backslash, i.e.

```
"C:\\mydirectory\\"...
```

Answer (score 2):

If trying to create it into the root, you may run into a permissions issue if not logged in as administrator.  Try creating it in a subdirectory.

Comment: I'm administrator :)
I also have tried this 

hfile = CreateFile(
        L"C:\Users\Vardan\Desktop\name.txt",    
        GENERIC_WRITE, 
        0,
     NULL,
        CREATE_NEW,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
     NULL);
but it didn't create any file

Comment: Being administrator and running the executable AS administrator are two different things.  But my other answer is more to the point -- square that away then try it in a subdirectory and you should get some joy.  (One way to ensure you're running as administrator is right click on the file in explorer, then "run as administrator").